# How can I use git rebase --empty=drop

Tags: git, rebase

I would like to use `git rebase`'s `--empty=drop` option, documented [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---emptydropkeepask).

When I run `git rebase -m --empty=drop`, git tells me `unknown option 'empty=drop'`.

How do I use this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git` version 2.25](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.25.0) doesn't have the option. Hence it was added in version 2.26.

Upgrade to use the option.

Comment: Ahh thanks. I did an apt update and upgrade before but ubuntu's version is evidently pretty out of date. Anyone else who encounters this should update git from [here](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Comment: @Vivalande Ha, Ubutntu… I recently bought a new laptop and installed Debian stable (currently Debian 10). On all my other computers (mostly servers) still Debian oldstable (Debian 9). `git` version 2.11.0. That's what you can name "pretty out of date". :-D *Upd*. Found an old server at the job: git version 1.8.3.1. OMG!

Comment: Last I saw, CentOS was still using Git 1.7.1 or 1.7.9. But 1.8.3.1 is pretty bad too. :-)